# What is wrong with the column checker for my tic tac toe game?

Tags: python

This is my tic tac toe web app. There's a `game.html` that's not included but can be if needed. The python code below can correctly identify if player X or O has 3 of their symbol in a row and will give them the victory. However, it cannot identify whether a player has 3 of their symbol in a column and I don't understand why despite following it carefully.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my column checking algorithm?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if "board" not in session:
        session["board"] = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
        session["turn"] = "X"
    winner = None
    for row in session["board"]:
        if set(row) == set("X"):
            winner = "X"
        if set(row) == set("O"):
            winner = "O"
    for i in range(3):
        col_lst = []
        for row in session["board"]:
            col_lst.append(row[i])
        if set(col_lst) == "X":
            winner = "X"
        if set(col_lst) == "O":
            winner = "O"
    return render_template("game.html", game=session["board"], turn=session["turn"], winner=winner)


@app.route("/play/<int:row>/<int:col>")
def play(row, col):
    session["board"][row][col] = session["turn"]
    if session["turn"] == "X":
        session["turn"] = "O"
    else:
        session["turn"] = "X"
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

Comment: Minor corrections grammar and capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. I had to put "X" and "O" in a set function similarly to the rows algorithm.

Comment: If that solvea your problem, please accept own answer.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I would but the interface says I have to wait 2 days.